# Android TensorFlow - prevent resize Image

Tags: android, image-processing, tensorflow, styles

I am working on TensorFlow stylize image. But, the problem I am facing is that it resize my actual image. I want to apply style on whole image itself. For example, if my image resolution is 1280x960, it should be the same after I apply style on it.

I am not using default INPUT_SIZE value 256. Using default value it works fine. Here is my code I am using to prevent resize image.

```
private TensorFlowInferenceInterface inferenceInterface;
private void applyStyle(){
    inferenceInterface = new TensorFlowInferenceInterface(mActivity.getAssets(), "bossK_float.pb");
    Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromPath();
    bitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap,0,bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    INPUT_SIZE_WIDTH = bitmap.getWidth();
    INPUT_SIZE_HEIGHT = bitmap.getHeight();
    mStyledBitmap = stylizeImage(bitmap);
}

private Bitmap stylizeImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
            Bitmap scaledBitmap = scaleBitmap(bitmap, INPUT_SIZE_WIDTH, INPUT_SIZE_HEIGHT);

            intValues = new int[INPUT_SIZE_WIDTH * INPUT_SIZE_HEIGHT];
            floatValues = new float[INPUT_SIZE_WIDTH * INPUT_SIZE_HEIGHT * 3];

            scaledBitmap.getPixels(intValues, 0, scaledBitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight());
            scaledBitmap = scaledBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);



            for (int i = 0; i < intValues.length; ++i) {
                final int val = intValues[i];
                floatValues[i * 3 + 0] = ((val >> 16) & 0xFF) * 1.0f;
                floatValues[i * 3 + 1] = ((val >> 8) & 0xFF) * 1.0f;
                floatValues[i * 3 + 2] = (val & 0xFF) * 1.0f;
            }
            Trace.beginSection("feed");
            inferenceInterface.feed(INPUT_NAME, floatValues, INPUT_SIZE_WIDTH, INPUT_SIZE_HEIGHT, 3);
            Trace.endSection();

            Trace.beginSection("run");
            inferenceInterface.run(new String[]{OUTPUT_NAME});
            Trace.endSection();

            Trace.beginSection("fetch");
            inferenceInterface.fetch(OUTPUT_NAME, floatValues);
            Trace.endSection();

            for (int i = 0; i < intValues.length; ++i) {
                intValues[i] =
                        0xFF000000
                                | (((int) (floatValues[i * 3 + 0])) << 16)
                                | (((int) (floatValues[i * 3 + 1])) << 8)
                                | ((int) (floatValues[i * 3 + 2]));
            }
            scaledBitmap.setPixels(intValues, 0, scaledBitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight());

            return scaledBitmap;
        }

    private Bitmap scaleBitmap(Bitmap origin, int newWidth, int newHeight) {
        if (origin == null) {
            return null;
        }
        int height = origin.getHeight();
        int width = origin.getWidth();
        float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
        float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
        Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(origin, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
        return newBitmap;
    }
```

When I change my INPUT_SIZE values to INPUT_SIZE_WIDTH and INPUT_SIZE_HEIGHT, my application stops without error message. I debug this code, but it stucks on this piece of code and stop my app:

```
Trace.beginSection("run");
inferenceInterface.run(new String[]{OUTPUT_NAME});
Trace.endSection();
```

Please let me know, how can I style whole image using TensorFlow.

Thank You!

Comment: You have to use the exact input size required by the model. If you want to use another input size, you have to **retrain** your model with another fixed input size or with a variable input size (which is more difficult).

However I wouldn't recommend to go for such a high input size, since this will give you a very poor performance on mobile devices.

Comment: @sladomic Thank you for you response! Yes, It is more difficult to have a variable input size in the model. But can you please tell me which size is perfect to work on every mobile device? I have model files with input size of 2000 and 1024, but both these are giving OOM.  As per my experience, I came to know that input size of 256 is working fine. I can't even use 512 as input size, it says too much process on Main thread although I am running it in AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

Your code stops there because of the differences in size. You probably must be getting an ArrayOutOfBound Exception.

The model is to be trained to accept images of a particular size. So, whenever you classify, the image is to be reduced to that particular size.

Even your training data which when creating a pb/lite/tflite file will be converted to accept the same size images you mention within the model creation. The results will not affect to a larger extinct. You can give that a try.